# Powershell to change taxonomy field value with condition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Below is my code. Currently it updates all the taxonomy field values in the document library. I just need to set a condition where Taxonomy column value(document library) is equal to "Termvalue2" then change to "TermValue1"

```
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -site 

$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"]

$termStoreGroup = $termStore.Groups["MyTermGroup"]

$termSet = $termStoreGroup.TermSets["Mytermset"]

$t = $termset.GetAllTerms()

$term = $t["TermValue1"]
```

##############################

```
$Site = Get-SPWeb 

$List = $Site.Lists["Site Documents"]
$taxField =[Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$List.Fields["MyField"]
$taxField.GetFieldValue()

foreach($i in $list.Items)
{
  $var = $listItems
  $taxField.SetFieldValue($i, $term) 
  $i.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the condition to check if the value of the managed metadata column is equal to “Termvalue2” in the loop foreach.

There is a demo for your reference. The “mm” is the managed metadata column in my document library.

```
Get-SPTaxonomySession -site http://sp:5872/
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -site http://sp:5872/
$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"]
$termStoreGroup = $termStore.Groups["People"]
$termSet = $termStoreGroup.TermSets["Department"]
$t = $termset.GetAllTerms()
$term = $t["1"]

$Site = Get-SPWeb http://sp:5872/
$list = $Site.Lists["doc1"]
$taxField =[Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$List.Fields["mm"]
foreach($i in $list.Items)
{
 $taxFieldValue = $i["mm"] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue];            
 $taxFieldValue.Label;
  if($taxFieldValue.Label -eq "test3")
  {
    $taxField.SetFieldValue($i, $term); 
    $i.update();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue with below code:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ab7464f8-510f-4932-8240-eff5b6e24a0f/powershell-to-change-taxonomy-field-value-with-condition?forum=sharepointdevelopment#91ccd658-a842-460c-b2ca-201c14195d12

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
#Variables
$WebURL="http://sp:12001"
$ListName="Documents"
$FieldName="MyField"

#Get the web
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL    

#Get the Term from Term store
$TaxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $web.Site
$TermStore = $TaxonomySession.TermStores["Mananged Metadata"]
$TermGroup = $TermStore.Groups["MyTermGroup"]
$TermSet = $TermGroup.TermSets["Mytermset"]
$Term = $Termset.Terms["TermValue1"]

#Use SharePoint Manager

#Get the List and List Item
$List= $Web.Lists[$listName]
foreach($i in $list.Items)
{   
    $taxFieldValue = $i["MyField"] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue];            
    $taxFieldValue.Label;   
    if($taxFieldValue.label -eq "termvalue2")
    {
        $taxField.SetFieldValue($i, $term) 
        $i.update();
    }
}

Write-host "Managed Metadata Field value updated!"
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me. I abandoned using the `SetFieldValue` altogether and did it this way instead:

```
$session = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $sList.ParentWeb.Site  
          
$termStore = $session.TermStores["My Managed Metadata"]
    
#get taxanomy group and termset

$termStoreGroup = $termStore.Groups["Enterprise Taxonomy"]

$termSetFiscalYear = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TermSet]

$termStoreGroup.TermSets["Fiscal Year"]
    
#get all terms for Fiscal year

$t = $termSetFiscalYear.GetAllTerms()

$termSetFiscalYearValueToSet = $t["0000-0000"]

foreach($spItem in $sListItems)
{

   $listTaxonomyFieldFiscalYear = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$sItem.Fields["FiscalYear"]

   $termString = $termSetFiscalYearValueToSet.Name + "|" + $termSetFiscalYearValueToSet.Id + ";"  

   $sItem["FiscalYear"] = $termString.Substring(0,$termString.Length-1) 

   $sItem.Update()

}
```